# Get char in the middle of the string YACC

Tags: c, yacc, lex

My question is kinda simple, i suppose. Here is my code,

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char const *c);

int yywarp(){
    return 1;
}
%}

%token LETTER MID

%%
input: {printf("Enter the polindrom:\n");}
    | input line;

line:   anal '\n'   {printf("good\n\n");}
    | error '\n'    {yyerrok;}
    ;

anal:   MID MID {
        printf("%d %d\n", $1, $2);

        if($1!=$2)
            YYERROR;
        }

    |LETTER anal LETTER {

        printf("%d %d\n", $1, $3);

        if($1!=$3)
            YYERROR;
        }
    ;

%%
int yylex(void)
{
    int c;
    char a[10];

    c = getchar();

    if(c == 'a'){
        yylval = c;
        return MID;
    }
    if(isalpha(c)){
        yylval = c;
        return LETTER;
    }

    if(c == EOF)
        return 0;

    return c;
}

void yyerror(char const *c)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", c);
}

int main(){
    return(yyparse());
}
```

As you can see, MID returns only when you input 'a'. My question is: how to get real middle element? The task is to recognize palindromes using YACC. But i think my teacher won't accept it if i just use "for" cycle for it.

Answer (score 1):

The language of palindromes is not LR(1), so `yacc` cannot generate a parser for it without an oracle that lets it know where the middle of the string is. Your example includes such an oracle; it is easy to do if the middle letter (or pair of letters) have a distinct value. If that is part of the problem specification, then you are basically on the right track.

`bison` could parse palindromes if you ask it to generate a `GLR` parser instead of an `LALR(1)` parser. The fact that you say `yacc` rather than `bison` suggests that this is not an appropriate solution, and it is not in general an appropriate solution because GLR parsers are not linear-time with grammars like this, whereas an obvious linear-time parsing solution exists.

If all else fails, you could simply parse the input into a list of characters, and check to see if it is a palindrome in the final reduction action.